# Heat transfer from one body to another by radiation

Tags: thermodynamics

How can I calculate the temperature of a metal if at a distance of 1mm there is another heated metal that is at 3000K?
Note: the system works in vacuum

Comment: You have to make some further assumptions like distance, absorbance, heat conductivity, and especially sizes. It's not generally analytic

Comment: @planetmaker ok the metal is a cylinder with surface: 3.1416mm2, and 10mm in length

Comment: Does the second metal object radiate into 2.3 K space?  In other words, don't consider the second metal object as only being an absorber of radiation ... it is also an emitter of radiation.